# Must memory of created System.RegularExpressions objects be released?

Tags: regex, delphi

I have this code using **System.RegularExpressions** in Delphi Rio 10.3.3:

```
var
  S: string;
  Itf: string; // Interface section
  TempList: TStringList;
  ThisRegexObj: System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx;
  ThisMatchResult: System.RegularExpressions.TMatch;
begin
  ThisRegexObj := System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Create(
    '((?<=procedure ).*(?=\())|(?<=procedure ).*(?!\()', [roIgnoreCase]);
  ThisMatchResult := ThisRegexObj.Match(Itf);
  TempList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    while ThisMatchResult.Success do
    begin
      TempList.Add(ThisMatchResult.Value);
      ThisMatchResult := ThisMatchResult.NextMatch;
    end;
    mmoTokens.Lines.Add('Interface Procedure names: ' + TempList.CommaText);
  finally
    TempList.Free;
  end;
```

Must the memory of the objects *ThisRegexObj* and *ThisMatchResult* be released afterwards?

Comment: I don't think so, they are declared as records. Anyway if you are not sure you can always enable [ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown) to check you don't leak objects...

Comment: The classic design flaw of record constructors named Create that don't follow the pattern of having a matching destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Must memory of created System.RegularExpressions objects be released?

*Objects* are instances of *classes*, and they always need to be freed.

However, `TRegEx` and `TMatch` aren't classes at all, but record types. Thus, your `ThisRegexObj` and `ThisMatchResult` aren't objects but records. And records are handled automatically by the compiler.

Hence, you need not free anything (indeed, you cannot do that -- there are no `Free` members on these records).

Comment: Is there a recipe to distinguish class from record when placing the cursor on identifier?

Comment: @user1580348: Unfortunately, no. But if you Ctrl-click a type name (`TRegEx` or `TForm`, say), you get to the type definition, where you can rapidly identify `TRegEx` as a record and `TForm` as a class. That's something I do often when I need to learn if a type is a class or a record (or something else, like an enumeration).

Comment: Note that object field types in a record needs to be released, since they are not managed by the compiler.

Comment: @LURD: Indeed. Such a record member is only a pointer to the actual object (or, a native-sized integer that *could* point to an object). The compiler will not attempt to do anything about the object it points to (if any).